# UWP - get first child of Gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, datagridview, uwp

```
<GridView x:Name="MainGridStations" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Stations}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Station">
                    <Grid x:Name="WantToSelectByCode">
                        <Grid Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                              <Grid Background="#e4f0fc" Height="65" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0.8">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="StationName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#2c9a8b" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I'm trying to select a child by index of a dynamically filled gridview but what i've tried always returns null.

Like so for the first child for example:

```
var container = MainGridStations.ContainerFromIndex(0);

var presenter = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(container, 0) as GridViewItem;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the corresponding `GridViewItem` from the method [ItemsControl.ContainerFromIndex(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.containerfromindex) directly and don't need to use the `VisualTreeHelper` to get it again.

```
var container = MainGridStations.ContainerFromIndex(0);
GridViewItem gridViewItem= container as GridViewItem;
gridViewItem.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

The `container` have been the corresponding `GridViewItem` got from the index.

Note that: since your inner Grid have a `Background="White"` property configuration, you can delete the code to see the effect more obviously using my above code to change the `gridViewItem.Background`.

---Update---

You must get the `GridViewItem` after the items loaded. You can try the code in your `GridView_ItemClick` event handler or the page's loaded event hander. Also pay attention to my above note that to get more obvious effect, please delete the `Background="White"` in your above xaml code.

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var container = MainGridStations.ContainerFromIndex(0);
    GridViewItem gridViewItem = container as GridViewItem;
    gridViewItem.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
}

//get the item here
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var container = MainGridStations.ContainerFromIndex(0);
    GridViewItem gridViewItem= container as GridViewItem;
    gridViewItem.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    //var presenter = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(container, 0) as GridViewItem;
}
```

Comment: I tried that too. It always returns null for some reason.